# jest spyOn mockimplementation on callback as argument not working

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

Here I'm trying to mock a function whose args is a callback function which setState inside. but I'm not able to cover this piece of code in code coverage.
Is this the right way to mock this function?

```
const func =()={
//some other logic
window.__promos.holiday.event('gift',(data)=>{
setState(data)
})
}
```

```
 test('window.__promo calls the callback function with the correct data', () => {
  // Spy on the callback function and provide a mock implementation
  jest.spyOn(window.__promo.holiday, 'event').mockImplementation(('gift', cb) => {
    cb('data');
  });
});
```

Comment: What's the test result and what do you expect?

Comment: need code coverage inside call back function, once the state is set expect that data to be same.